# Apache listening on 80 routing everything to nodejs listening on port 8080

Tags: apache-2.2, port

I have an Apache server handling many VirtulServers and everything works fine. I don't know how it works internally but it does.

I recently tinkered a bit with nodejs, making experiments on this server, on the 8080 port. Now that I want to go on production, I have set up a domain name pointing to my server, but I want to avoid the ugly example.org:8080/ URL that I have at the moment. How could I tell Apache, which is listening on 80, to route traffic from example.org to 123.12.12.123:8080 and vice-versa? I have tried ModRewrite but specifying the port and domain forces it to appear in the address bar of a browser, which is even uglier. I have tried ModProxy but to no success (500 error). What should I try next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mod_proxy should works, here's a tuto of it : http://davybrion.com/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache/

Comment: Oh man this is working, I am so happy. I had lost faith in all that. I was doing everything right but proxy_http was not loaded. 48hours of headache are now gone. 10000 thanks again